# Stop Read Replica Instance on GCP CloudSQL

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, cloud-sql-proxy, gcloud-compute

To stop a cloudsql instance

```
gcloud sql instances patch INSTANCE_NAME --activation-policy=NEVER
```

We tried and it failed for read replicas instances

```
ERROR: (gcloud.sql.instances.patch) HTTPError 400: Invalid request: Invalid flag for instance role: Activation policy for replica must be set to ALWAYS, currently 'NEVER'..
```

Now as per the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/start-stop-restart-instance#activation_policy), we can't set the `NEVER` for read replicas.

[image]

Is there any way to stop the read replica instance of `cloudsql` along with main instance properly ?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to **delete both** Cloud SQL ***instance*** and ***read replica***, is that correct?

Comment: Nope I clearly mentioned that I want to stop the instance :) .

Answer (score 1):

For us to stop read replication, we have two options:

- [Disable replication](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/replication/manage-replicas#disable_replication)
- Delete read replica

**Disable Replication**

1. Go to [Cloud SQL Instance](https://console.cloud.google.com/sql?_ga=2.123383563.1603107536.1678381379-679303749.1678381379) page
2. Select the read replica you want to disable

   [image: 3]
3. Click `DISABLE REPLICATION` then click on `DISABLE` when a pop-up display

   [image: 4]

**Delete Read Replica**

1. Go to [Cloud SQL Instance](https://console.cloud.google.com/sql?_ga=2.123383563.1603107536.1678381379-679303749.1678381379) page
2. Select the read replica you want to disable

   [image: 3]
3. Click on `EDIT` and make sure that under **Data Protection**, **Enable deletion protection** is unchecked then click on `SAVE`.

   [image: 5]

   [image: 6]
4. Click `DELETE` then type in the `read-replica-name` when a pop-up display

   [image: 7]

   [image: 8]

Comment: I didn't mention anywhere in my question `delete read replica` :).

Comment: If i follow step 1 only and disable replication, it will still incur some cost, I want to stop the instance and start it back after some time.

Comment: @shubham, as of the moment, we could only disable read replica and even if it's disabled, it would still incur charges as it is still an instance based on this documentation on [disabling replication](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/replication/manage-replicas#disable_replication). That is why I added the option to delete the read replica if you don't want to incur charges on the disabled read replica. It is only optional.